# How to match text data between two HTML in C

Tags: html, c

An interview programming problem in C, I need to match the text present in two HTML formatted strings.

Here are the two sample strings

```html
<html><p>Hello</p></html>

<html><p><b>H</b>ello</p></html>
```

Would want to discuss the best approach, here is my initial thought process

1. Remove HTML tags from the givem strings

```js
   void remove_html(char* str) {
        char* html_str = str;
        while(*str) {
            if(*html_str == '<')
                while(*html_str && *html_str++ != '>');
            *str++ = *html_str++; 
        }
    }
```

2. Once strings are extracted them we can match them.

Thanks!

Comment: "A small programming problem" you say. Unfortunately this isn't small. You cannot parse generic html like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I gather your requirement correctly, I think it would be simpler to just write a function that skips XML tags to get at the actual text. Then use it as the step function in a normal loop:

```
char const* skip_html(char const *str)
{
  if(!str)
    return NULL;

  while(*str && *str == '<') {
    // Must be a loop, to skip consecutive tags

    while (*str && *str++ != '>')
      ; // No-op. Increment in the loop condition

    // Here str points past the '>' or at the end.
  }

  return str;
} 

// Must be passed valid string pointers, otherwise the behavior is undefined
bool compare_string_with_embedded_html(char const *lhs, char const *rhs) {
  for (lhs = skip_html(lhs), rhs = skip_html(rhs);
       *lhs && *rhs;
       lhs = skip_html(++lhs), rhs = skip_html(++rhs)) {

    if (*lhs != *rhs)
      return false;
  }

  return *lhs == *rhs; // True only if both point at the end of each respective
                       // string.
}
```

If you actually care about the *structure* of the HTML, then this won't work. You'd need a proper parser.

Comment: Upvoted for short-circuiting behaviour, even though modern HTML isn't XML. This (like OP's code) would also fail in `<script>`s as they will often have unescaped `<`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - I concur that it will fail gloriously if the structure of the markup is of any value. I hope the OP heeds my disclaimer at the end (and your comment).